# How to generate an index for a file?

Tags: python

For instance if a file has

```
xxx|12

yyy|13

zzz|14
```

I need the output to be

```
1 xxx|12

2 yyy|13

3 zzz|14
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: it's not python but if you are using unix you can use the __nl__ command : http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_nl.htm

Comment: You mean you want to enumerate the lines?

Comment: What is the relevance of the Python tag? There are a number of utilities that are better-suited to this task.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, Python is also suited for this task. Its just programming..much like anything else

Comment: @Kurumi: the task can be achieved in Python, sure. But there's nothing in the question that suggests that this particular problem should require the likes of `nl` to be rewritten. Nor is there any suggestion that Bharani has attempted any of this in Python, Perl or Logo before asking the advice of other programmers.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, if he has put a Python tag on, then why doesn't it occur to you (or those who voted up your comments) that he really wants to do it with Python? While i am sure `nl` can do it, but what if he doesn't have it and maybe he is working on Windows? All these we do not know, so don't be too quick to judge. The very least we as solution providers can do is to tackle the question at hand (without thinking/guessing too deep), no matter how incomplete the requirement are.

Comment: @Kurumi: Excellent! Could you please write me a foreign exchange trading website? In Perl? kthxbai.

Comment: @Bharani: It's unclear if your input file has blank lines in it that you want skipped, or the blank lines are just an artifact of the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
import fileinput
f=fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1)
for line in f:
     print  f.lineno(), line
```

there are many other ways to do it. If you are on a linux/unix system

```
awk '{print NR,$0}' file
cat -n file
sed '=' file
nl file
```

Also Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ne 'print "#{$.} #{$_}"' file
```

Comment: Thanks Kurumi . As u have discussed i wanted the answer only in Python .

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()`.

```
f = open('input_file')
data = f.read().split()
f.close()

data = ["%d %s" % (idx + 1, x) for idx, x in enumerate(data)]
data = " ".join(data)

f = open('output_file', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: If you want to enumerate lines instead of words, use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read()`.

Comment: Or just iterate over the file-object directly - this will read the file line-by-line. Also, you should use `with` instead of manually closing the file.

Comment: Before the OP edited the question, the words were in one row, so the `for line in file` syntax wouldn't have worked. I did not use `with` because I did not want to confuse the OP with syntax that he maybe could not have understood.

Comment: I believe that it is important to write example code that sets a good example. If the OP is confused by `with`, he can look it up, or ask a question about it. But if he never sees it, he will never even think of using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputfile = open('filein.txt', 'r')
outputfile = open('fileout.txt', 'w')
count = 1

for line in inputfile:
    outputfile.write(str(count) + " " + line)
    count += 1    

outputfile.close()
inputfile.close()
```

et voile.

Comment: You do not need a counter here, this is what `enumerate` is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputfile = open('filein.txt', 'r')
outputfile = open('fileout.txt', 'w')


for index, line in enumerate(inputfile, 1):
    outputfile.write("%d %s" %(index, line))

outputfile.close()
inputfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your input had some empty lines, anyway here you go:

```
text=open('input.txt','r')
lines=text.readlines()
text.close()

output=open('output.txt','w')

for lineNumber in range(len(lines)):
    if lines[lineNumber] not in ["","\n","\t"]:
        output.write(str(lineNumber)+" "+lines[lineNumber])
    else:
        output.write(lines[lineNumber])
```